# Opposite of aspnet_regiis -ga <UserName>

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am looking to deny access using aspnet_regiis and was hoping if anyone knew how to do this. So the opposite of this:

```
aspnet_regiis -ga <UserName>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to

http://forums.asp.net/t/1307213.aspx

this is not possible.

If this is a common requirement, use the -ga switch with a group that You then can add/remove users to/from.

/Andreas